# Random Word in Front of Each Line in a File

Tags: php, file, random

I want to add a random text in front of every line, like this:

Before:

```
One
Two
Three
```

After:

```
Love One
My Two
Other Three
```

Update :
Sorry for the confusion, I mean the 'before' text is a textarea submitted text so its in $_POST value and I want the result like the 'after' text. In simple, the code like this :
Let assume that the before text is under $_POST['message'] value, and I want to **echo** the value but with random text in front of it.

I try this but only work for the first line and not the other line :

```
$rand = array("Love", "My", "Other");
$message = trim(@$_POST['message']) ;
$message = str_replace(" ","+",$message);//Convert the space to +
$modifiedTextAreaText = str_replace( "\n", "\n$rand", $message);//This One Not Working
echo $rand[array_rand($rand, 1)]. $modifiedTextAreaText ;//This one working only for the first line
```

Thanks

Comment: Where are you sourcing this text from?

Comment: I didn't understand your question.

Comment: what kind of random? you can get a random text from array, and you can take a random from auto generated text? so what type do you need??

Comment: are these printable strings?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please follow the [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) you needed to confirm before posting *any* question. Keep in mind that only you want something and you ask yourself how it is programmed does not qualify as a programming question per-se.

Comment: Already update the question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean like this:

```
<?php

$randomWords = array('Love', 'My', 'Other');

$randomKey = array_rand($randomWords, 1);
echo $randomWords[$randomKey] . " One<br />";

$randomKey = array_rand($randomWords, 1);
echo $randomWords[$randomKey] . " Two<br />";

$randomKey = array_rand($randomWords, 1);
echo $randomWords[$randomKey] . " Three<br />";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build arrays, then shuffle both or just the one you want randomized. then combine the two.

```
<?php
$rands = array("Love", "My", "Other");
shuffle($rands);
$words = array("One", "Two", "Three");
$new = array_combine($rands, $words);

foreach($new as $key => $val){
    echo "$key $val<br />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set the texts you want in an array and call for rand() function with your array element key and then print the element
example

```
$text = array( 0=> "text0", 1=> "text1", 2=> "text2");
$randomtext = rand (0,2);
echo $text['$randtext'];
```

Comment: you have array_rand() for such stuff.